# how to make these 2 files into a funtional program

Tags: java, file, class, user-interface

My professor told me to put both of these together to make a running program. I am utilizing Netbeans, and it keeps telling me that there is no main class. Am I supposed to create one or am I missing something? How do I put these together into a working gui java application?

Here is the first file, it is called NumberGame

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NumberGame {
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int min, max;
    private int num1, num2;

    public NumberGame(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        newNums();
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }

    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }

    public void newNums() {
        num1 = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        num2 = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public int calcSum() {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public boolean checkSum(int num) {
        return num == calcSum();
    }
}
```

The second file is called App here it is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class App extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    /* Canvas ============================================ */
    private NumberGame numbers;
    private Font mainFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN,16);

    /* Components for Canvas ============================= */
    private JTextField messageField;
    private JLabel lblNum1;
    private JLabel lblNum2;
    private JTextField sumField;
    private JButton btnNext;
    private JButton btnCheck;


    public App(String title, int width, int height) {
        // initialize new number game
        numbers = new NumberGame(10, 49);

        // initialize components
        messageField = new JTextField("", 10);
        messageField.setEditable(false);
        messageField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        messageField.setFont(mainFont);

        // add components to board
        add(messageField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(createCenter(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // add action listeners
        btnCheck.addActionListener(this);
        btnNext.addActionListener(this);
        sumField.addActionListener(this);

        // create the window
        createWindow(title, width, height);
        pack();
    }

    private void createWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JPanel createCenter() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

        JLabel lblNumPrompt1 = new JLabel("Number 1 = ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        lblNumPrompt1.setFont(mainFont);
        lblNum1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(numbers.getNum1()), JLabel.CENTER);
        lblNum1.setFont(mainFont);

        JLabel lblNumPrompt2 = new JLabel("Number 2 = ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        lblNumPrompt2.setFont(mainFont);
        lblNum2 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(numbers.getNum2()), JLabel.CENTER);
        lblNum2.setFont(mainFont);

        JLabel lblSumPrompt = new JLabel("Sum = ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        lblSumPrompt.setFont(mainFont);
        sumField = new JTextField("0", 10);
        sumField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        sumField.setFont(mainFont);

        // add objects to the panel
        panel.add(lblNumPrompt1);
        panel.add(lblNum1);
        panel.add(lblNumPrompt2);
        panel.add(lblNum2);
        panel.add(lblSumPrompt);
        panel.add(sumField);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnCheck = new JButton("Check");

        panel.add(btnNext);
        panel.add(btnCheck);

        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if (button.equals(btnNext)) {
            numbers.newNums();
            lblNum1.setText(Integer.toString(numbers.getNum1()));
            lblNum2.setText(Integer.toString(numbers.getNum2()));
        } else {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(sumField.getText());

            if (numbers.checkSum(num))
                messageField.setText("Correct!");
            else
                messageField.setText("Try Again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need a class with a main function that initializes your gui in the swing thread.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to create a `main` class. That is part of the "make a running program" assignment.

Comment: I really appreciate the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a main class and initialize the app class as below, HTH.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   //Put in the title and size of the Panel
   App app1 = new App("MY game", 1000, 900);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **main** class .
2. Put all 3 classes into same **package**.
3. Simply create an object of **App** class in **main** class.
4. Run the **main** class.